# Get the canvas object while using fabric js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm using Fabric.js and I've created a fabric canvas object at one place.

```
var x = new fabric.Canvas("mycanvas");
```

Now at another place, I want to access this object where 'x' won't be available. So how can I get the same fabric canvas object.

I don't wanna change the scope of x or pass x as arg.

Also, how to get the toDataURL from the fabric canvas object?

Comment: If you don't make the reference available, it won't be able to be accessed. That's how scope works.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming that `mycanvas` is the ID of a Canvas element, you could store the reference to the fabric object on the Canvas element itself:

```
var x = new fabric.Canvas("mycanvas");
document.getElementById("mycanvas").fabric = x;
```

You can then retrieve that object any time you want with:

```
var y = document.getElementById("mycanvas").fabric;
var url = y.toDataURL("png", 1);
```

Comment: y is the fabric canvas object so you will need to use toDataURL differently [see this](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#toDataURL)