# Cannot use getActiveObject() in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I want to check the image quality of the selected image on canvas.

My following code:

```
var canvas = $(".canvas-container").children('canvas').get(0);
//console.log(canvas.getActiveObject().get('type'));
console.log(canvas);
```

The getActiveObject() log gives an error:
 undefined is not a function.

The other log returns:

```
<canvas class="lower-canvas" width="850" height="230" style="position: absolute; width: 850px; height: 230px; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-user-select: none;"></canvas>
```

The canvas is created in another js file:

```
      //create fabric stage
        var canvas = $productStage.children('canvas').get(0);

        stage = new fabric.Canvas(canvas, {
            selection: false,
            hoverCursor: 'pointer',
            rotationCursor: 'default',
            controlsAboveOverlay: true,
            centeredScaling: true
        });
```

What must I change so I can use so I can use canvas.getActiveObject()?

See http://www.panel-it.eu/shop/straatnaambord-3/# for reference.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

`getActiveObject()` is a method of a [fabric.Canvas](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html) object.

With the above code, you would use `stage.getActiveObject()` instead of `canvas.getActiveObject()`

Comment: If I use stage.getActiveObject() the console says undefined.


console.log(stage.getActiveObject());

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you have lost the reference to the fabric.Canvas object you created called `stage`, then perhaps you should attach it to the HTMLElement object of the canvas when you initialize the fabric Canvas. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13195555/3538503 for an example.